# Passing cookie data between iframes

Tags: php, javascript, apache, iframe, cookies

Say I have a website, www.example.com, with a login box which sits in an iframe situated in api.example.com. My question is:

1. Is it possible to pass cookie data from the inner iframe (api.example.com to the website, so the website knows when the user logged in?
2. Is it possible to do this client-side, without the need to refresh the whole page? How would the fact that user logged in be passed to the website?

Any solution which works on FF and IE 6/7 would be great.

Comment: Please add tag for your serverside platform

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to pass the cookie between them.  You need to write the cookie to the right domain though.

```
Response.Cookies("COOKIENAME").Domain = ".example.com"
Response.Cookies("COOKIENAME").Value= "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

A cookie can be shared between two domains like `api.example.com` and `www.example.com` by having the server specify the cookie domain to be simply `example.com`.  This makes the cookie available to both sub-domains.

FF3 and IE8 support then [postMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197015(VS.85).aspx) standard which allow windows(frames) in different domains to talk to each other.  However for IE6/7 you would need an AJAX call to the server to get what ever login confirmation you need but tricky thing would be knowing how to trigger such a request.